# Jquery not loading from static files

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

This is my project structure:

```
pack
├── mysite
│   ├── blog
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── db.sqlite3
│   ├── manage.py
│   ├── mssql_app
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   ├── forms_old.py
│   │   ├── forms.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── models.txt
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── routers.py
│   │   ├── templates
│   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   ├── views_old.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── mysite
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── settings.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── wsgi.py
│   └── static
│       ├── admin
│       └── js
             └── jquery-3.1.1.min.js
└── venv
```

In `settings.py` there is:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mysite/static')
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")
```

I'm trying to load jquery in `~/pack/mysite/mssql_app/templates/base.html` as follows:

```
{% load static %}<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"> 
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js' %}"></script>
 
  
  <title>{% block title %}Packing{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
```

But `python manage.py runserver` writes:

```
"GET /static/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1690
```

Here is `~/pack/mysite/mysite/urls.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'', include('mssql_app.urls')),
]
```

and `~/pack/mysite/mssql_app/urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.show, name ='show'),
    url(r'create', views.create, name ='create'),
    url(r'save_pw', views.save_pw, name ='save_pw'),
]
```

How can I fix it?

The solution from @Lakshyaraj Dash helped, but `jquery` doesn't work when deploying the project with `apache2`. Isn't there some universal settings which work after deployment as well? Or what are the steps to do (regarding to static files) when deploying the app?

Comment: What is inside js folder?, by using static tags, we get path till the static directory. Does you worked with cdn, does cdn working perfectly or gives same error? one time check that.

Comment: Can you please change the file name to only `jq.js` and then check.

Comment: Change your `STATICFILES_DIRS` to only `os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static/`)` one time, see if it's works, may be not finding the static paths.

Comment: @SunderamDubey When I change it to `os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static/)` it gives this error `django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
?: (staticfiles.E002) The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting.
`

Comment: If debug is true then keep STATICFILES_DIRS else remove STATICFILES_DIRS and run command `python manage.py collectstatic`

Comment: @SmitParmar debug is true

Comment: @xralf try `STATICFILES_DIRS = [ os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]` and remove STATIC_ROOT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the STATICFILES_DIRS write down

```py
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
]
```

Keep either one configuration STATICFILES_DIRS or STATIC_ROOT.

Static root can be used only when the debug is false.

Comment: This helped. Could you please describe what to do when going into production? I need to use `python manage.py collectstatic`.

Comment: When I run the deployed application with `apache2` `jquery` doesn't work.

Comment: According to [this](https://dev.to/learndjango/django-static-files-tutorial-1fg7) tutorial I added a line `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')` and it works after deployment as well.

Comment: Listen static_root is for deployment purposes. You can view the django and deployment courses of codewithharry in Hindi **if you are Indian else view the django course of programmingwithharry.